# Scrapped views are getting displayed in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

ItemView which was previously added in the recyclerview is not getting removed when items are updated.

In the below image, there are getting two section A's which are not removed.

Please suggest any solution.

**when data is displayed first time.**

[image]

---

### When data is refreshed views get stuck

[image]

Comment: did u removed from data source as well...?

Comment: Yes i have removed.

Answer (score 0):

The view which was getting visible when dataset changed are views which are cached.
So to prevent RecyclerView caching the detached but not recycled views use:

```
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0)
```

with setting the cache size to zero now detached views are not getting cached but recycled views are .